# Approximation of indicator of a compact set in Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

My question is: Let $ K $ be a compact set of $ \mathbb{R}^N,\ N \geq 2.  $ Can we construct a sequence $ \phi_n \in W^{1,p}( \mathbb{R}^N) \cap L^{\infty}( \mathbb{R}^N) $ such that $ \phi_n \geq \chi_K,\ \phi_n \to \chi_K $ a.e. in $ \mathbb{R}^N, $ and  $$
\left| \nabla \phi_n\right|_{L^p( \mathbb{R}^N)} \to 0,\ n \to + \infty, $$ where $ p > 1. $
I tried with the convolution  $ \chi_K * \rho_n $ where $ \rho_n $ is a sequence of mollifiers but the third condition (concerning the norm of the gradient) cannot be established. Any help is welcome.

Comment: This is not possible, since otherwise it would follow (via the dual characterization of the space $W^{1,p}$ that the indicator $1_K$ is an element of $W^{1,p}$, which is not true.

Comment: How? More details please.